# Node test runner, group multiple tests together

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-test-runner

I've multiple tests that I'd like to group together.

I'm currently using `require` to group them under a common `describe` ancestor:

```
// all tests
describe('Some feature',() => {
  require('some_use_case');
  require('another_use_case');
});

describe('Another feature',() => {
  require('yet_another_use_case');
});

// and then in some_use_case.ts
describe('Some use case',() => {
  it('should do something');
});
```

which correctly groups the tests as I want:

```
Some Feature
  Some Use case:
    should do something.
  Another Use Case: 
    ...
```

The issue is the paths in `require` have to be kept in sync when modifying a file name and the IDE doesn't do it by itself.

Note: I'm just wondering if there is a *simple* way of achieving this. I do not want to play with custom formatters etc.